# How to generate color code dynamically by swapping 2 characters within a string using PHP

Tags: php, string, chart.js

`3BD1E9` this is my input and I want to swap 4th and 5th position

The output should be 3BDE19. I want a better solution.

I have tried this:

```
$color="3BD1E9";
$temp=$color[3];
$bgcolor=substr_replace(substr_replace($color,$color[4],3,1),$temp,4,1);
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use index to access a char of string like access an array. Check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/806083)**.

```
<?php
$color="3BD1E9";
$temp = $color[4];
$color[4] = $color[3];
$color[3] = $temp;
echo $color;
```